# get Access VBA have a Sender

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Access I have a form that has about 200 text boxes on it. I Know that in C# on every on click event there is `textbox1_Click(object sender)`. 
how can I in VBA have reference the current **sender** without saying Me.txt_Whatever?

this is what I have so far

```
Private Sub txtHotMix_DblClick(Cancel As Integer, sender As Object)
    Dim txt As TextBox
    Set txt = sender
    MsgBox txt.Name
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `ActiveControl` property of the `Screen` object is what you're after (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225491(v=office.12).aspx):

In a module:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub ctrl_Print(objCtrl As Control)

    MsgBox objCtrl.Value, vbOKOnly, "Control Value"

End Sub
```

You would still have to add a click event to every control to call this sub, like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Text0_Click()

    Call ctrl_Print(Screen.ActiveControl)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.